# What is done when an urgent fix for an app is needed but updates have to be approved by Apple/Google etc?

Tags: mobile, game-development, app, appstore, games

I have very little experience in this area, so sorry if I use any incorrect terminology or if this is a stupid/simplistic question in general.

But from what I understand, when a developer wants to push out an update for an app, it has to be approved by Apple/Google which can take up to 2 days. And apparently it even use to be much longer with Apple. So what happens if, for example, a massively popular game on an app store gets found out to have a huge exploit which could lead to players seeing other players credit card details, as an extreme example. Is there a way to bypass these wait times to push out a fix?

And I've heard of server side hotfixes in games before, so I assume these can be done to bypass these approval systems. And if so, doesn't that make the approval system pointless? I understand that hotfixes don't require the user to manually download a new update, but couldn't hotfixes still be used to do malicious things which I assume these approval systems are in place to prevent?

I guess my questions boil down to:
Why are these approval systems in place?
What can be done if there's a major exploit within a game that cannot be fixed by a hotfix?

Comment: You never see the payment info of your customers, Apple / Google handle that for you (so they can take their cut). Ditto other PII

Comment: Is your question "how do we fix the bad behavior of developers who abuse their hot-patching privileges?"  I think the answer to that is obvious.  But that seems like a question for Apple, not us.

Comment: The answer to "Why are these approval systems in place" is also obvious: to prevent abuse from occurring in the first place.

Comment: "What can be done if there's a major exploit within a game that cannot be fixed by a hotfix?" -- I guess you wait out the two days, or contact Apple for an exemption.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable or on-topic as asked but it's an interesting counter-point to the idea of 'move fast and break things'.  When you don't control the deployment channel, there's additional risk with a new release.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay I guess an approval system is probably better than no approval system. But I just find it interesting that they have these rules in place when something malicious could be hotfixed in straight after it's approved. I was just wondering if maybe my understanding of hotfixes were wrong and they couldn't be used maliciously. But I guess not and that's interesting to me. As for the major exploit question, I think it would be interesting to know what this process is like and if Apple would give special treatment to bigger developers/apps etc.

Comment: @Caleth It was just an example to suggest high severity. For a more real world example, I use to play a game back in the day that had quite a big "economy". Items were sold on 3rd party websites for large amount of money and it was a big part of the appeal of the game. One day people found a way to duplicate items, thousands if not millions of items were flooded into the game and it changed the game forever. I just find the concept interesting that if it were an app, the future of the game/developer would have been at the mercy of Apple's approval system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multiplayer software consists of client which is on the mobile device and service in internet. The service you host independently on the mobile vendors.

The answer to your question is that **you don't rely security on the client**. There are many reasons to. It may be obsolete, even if you roll out the update not everybody install it, and it is always possible to reverse engineer the client and write a crafted software which pretends to be the one.

If you implement authorization checks in the service you do not have to wait anybody's approval to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Any large scale process with have an escalation and/or exception approval process. The owner of the process then will state the requirements for an expedited publishing process. Typically, you would need to provide a business case explaining the urgency. Often, you will need director or VP level sign off from your own company as well as the owner of the app store.

On the developer end, on every release you should branch. You can then make small changes to that branch so you can re-release with just a bug fix and not all the other churn that might have gotten into the branch as part of regular development.

I got 7.2m hits searching for 'app store expedited publishing', I am sure the individual app store's policies will have more detail on how this can be handled.

The level of service will likely also depend on your level of revenue. If you are Candy Crush likely you already have been given a human on call 24/7 for you to deal with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Apple for an emergency (expedited) review, which will happen within an hour. Don’t do it often. I had to do it once in my life. Removed the old app, wrote the fix, and submitted it as an emergency. They might check that you have removed the old app - if you didn’t and allow users to download the old app then it can’t be that urgent.

Your server software is on your server and never gets reviewed. Except of course your app must work with your server. So there you can do what you like.